# Splitting bracket delimited text which can contain quoted strings

Tags: python, regex, pyparsing, state-machine

I am trying to split some text. Basically I want to separate level-1 brackets, like `"('1','a',NULL),(2,'b')"` => `["('1','a',NULL)", "(2,'b')]"`, but I need to be aware of possible quoted strings inside. It needs to at least satisfy the following py.tests:

```
from splitter import split_text


def test_normal():
    assert split_text("('1'),('2')") == ["('1')", "('2')"]
    assert split_text("(1),(2),(3)") == ["(1)", "(2)", "(3)"]


def test_complex():
    assert split_text("('1','a'),('2','b')") == ["('1','a')", "('2','b')"]
    assert split_text("('1','a',NULL),(2,'b')") == ["('1','a',NULL)", "(2,'b')"]


def test_apostrophe():
    assert split_text("('\\'1','a'),('2','b')") == ["('\\'1','a')", "('2','b')"]


def test_coma_in_string():
    assert split_text("('1','a,c'),('2','b')") == ["('1','a,c')", "('2','b')"]


def test_bracket_in_string():
    assert split_text("('1','a)c'),('2','b')") == ["('1','a)c')", "('2','b')"]


def test_bracket_and_coma_in_string():
    assert split_text("('1','a),(c'),('2','b')") == ["('1','a),(c')", "('2','b')"]


def test_bracket_and_coma_in_string_apostrophe():
    assert split_text("('1','a\\'),(c'),('2','b')") == ["('1','a\\'),(c')", "('2','b')"]
```

I have tried the following:

**1) Regular expressions**

This looks like the best solution, but unfortunately I did not come up with anything satisfying all tests.

My best try is:

```
def split_text(text):
    return re.split('(?<=\)),(?=\()', text)
```

But obviously, that is rather simplistic and fails  `test_bracket_and_coma_in_string` and `test_bracket_and_coma_in_string_apostrophe`.

**2) Finite-state-machine-like solution**

I tried to code the FSM myself:

```
OUTSIDE, IN_BRACKETS, IN_STRING, AFTER_BACKSLASH = range(4)


def split_text(text):
    state = OUTSIDE
    read = []
    result = []

    for character in text:
        if state == OUTSIDE:
            if character == ',':
                result.append(''.join(read))
                read = []
            elif character == '(':
                read.append(character)
                state = IN_BRACKETS
            else:
                read.append(character)

        elif state == IN_BRACKETS:
            read.append(character)
            if character == ')':
                state = OUTSIDE
            elif character == "'":
                state = IN_STRING

        elif state == IN_STRING:
            read.append(character)
            if character == "'":
                state = IN_BRACKETS
            elif character == '\\':
                state = AFTER_BACKSLASH

        elif state == AFTER_BACKSLASH:
            read.append(character)
            state = IN_STRING

    result.append(''.join(read))  # The rest of string
    return result
```

It works, passes all tests, but is **very slow**.

**3) pyparsing**

```
from pyparsing import QuotedString, ZeroOrMore, Literal, Group, Suppress, Word, nums

null_value = Literal('NULL')
number_value = Word(nums)
string_value = QuotedString("'", escChar='\\', unquoteResults=False)
value = null_value | number_value | string_value
one_bracket = Group(Literal('(') + value + ZeroOrMore(Literal(',') + value) + Literal(')'))
all_brackets = one_bracket + ZeroOrMore(Suppress(',') + one_bracket)


def split_text(text):
    parse_result = all_brackets.parseString(text)
    return [''.join(a) for a in parse_result]
```

Also passes all tests, but surprisingly it is **even slower** than solution #2.

Any ideas how to make the solution fast and robust? I have this feeling that I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use the newer [**`regex`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module which supports the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` functionality:

```
import regex as re

def split_text(text):
    rx = r"""'.*?(?<!\\)'(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<=\)),(?=\()"""
    return re.split(rx, text)
```

Broken down it says:

```
'.*?(?<!\\)'     # look for a single quote up to a new single quote
                 # that MUST NOT be escaped (thus the neg. lookbehind)
(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|  # these parts shall fail
(?<=\)),(?=\()   # your initial pattern with a positive lookbehind/ahead
```

This [**succeeds on all your examples**](https://regex101.com/r/oP4bP1/3).

Comment: Interesting, I did not know about the library. For a few reasons I cannot use it, but will keep an eye on it. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

I cooked this and it works on given tests.

```
tests = ["('1'),('2')",
"(1),(2),(3)",
"('1','a'),('2','b')",
"('1','a',NULL),(2,'b')",
"('\\'1','a'),('2','b')",
"('1','a,c'),('2','b')",
"('1','a)c'),('2','b')",
"('1','a),(c'),('2','b')",
"('1','a\\'),(c'),('2','b')"]

for text in tests:
    tmp = ''
    res = []
    bracket = 0
    quote = False

    for idx,i in enumerate(text):
        if i=="'":
            if text[idx-1]!='\\':
                quote = not quote
            tmp += i
        elif quote:
            tmp += i
        elif i==',':
            if bracket: tmp += i
            else:   pass
        else:
            if i=='(':      bracket += 1
            elif i==')':    bracket -= 1

            if bracket:   tmp += i
            else:
                tmp += i
                res.append(tmp)
                tmp = ''

    print res
```

Output:

```
["('1')", "('2')"]
['(1)', '(2)', '(3)']
["('1','a')", "('2','b')"]
["('1','a',NULL)", "(2,'b')"]
["('\\'1','a')", "('2','b')"]
["('1','a,c')", "('2','b')"]
["('1','a)c')", "('2','b')"]
["('1','a),(c')", "('2','b')"]
["('1','a\\'),(c')", "('2','b')"]
```

The code has room for improvement, and edits are welcome. :)

Comment: Do you think it is going to be faster than solutions #2 and #3?

Comment: So IMHO it is more or less FSM and speed on real data is comparable to solution #2.

Comment: The solution is O(n) for each string, where n is the length of the string. So, yeah this is the fastest you can get because you will need to scan the string at least once.

Comment: Comparing to solution #2, I'd say mine is shorter. Approach wise, they are similar, and both of them are O(n).

Comment: The difference in running time, if any, would be because of the implementation. Btw, can you share how you are deciding whether an algorithm is slow or not?

Comment: So my thinking is like this: If I can write a state machine, which solves the problem, the solution needs to solve problem around regular language / grammar. The complexity of all state machine solutions will be the same. However, implementing it in Python, e.g. reading it character by character, comparing etc., is going to be slow. Because the state machines and regular expressions have the same deciding equivalence, there should be a regular expression, which can solve the same problem. Because using regular expression is just a one function delegated to C code, it should much faster.

Comment: Now for comparing slow/fast, I have ~5GB text files, which are going to be converted periodically. Running the conversion using FSM (yours or mine, does not really matter), it takes about 60 minutes. Running with regular expression (unfortunately buggy one) takes 10 minutes. So IMHO I either need a regular expression which solves the same problem as your or mine FSM, or I need to find a way how to delegate more work from those to functions implemented in native C code.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing(about a regular expression existing for this). Great that you could figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regular expression which seems to work and passes all the tests. Running it on real data it is about 6x faster than finite state machine implemented in Python.

```
PATTERN = re.compile(
    r"""
        \(  # Opening bracket

            (?:

            # String
            (?:'(?:
               (?:\\')|[^']  # Either escaped apostrophe, or other character
               )*'
            )
            |
            # or other literal not containing right bracket
            [^')]

            )

            (?:, # Zero or more of them separated with comma following the first one

            # String
            (?:'(?:
               (?:\\')|[^']  # Either escaped apostrophe, or other character
               )*'
            )
            |
            # or other literal
            [^')]

            )*

        \)  # Closing bracket
    """,
    re.VERBOSE)


def split_text(text):
    return PATTERN.findall(text)
```